# How to combine 2 git repositories into one project

Tags: github

I have 2 git repositories with 2 different urls clientApp and serverApp
I want to have 1 project repository for this called App that consists of those .. 
How do I do that in github? something similar to group projects in gitlab..

Comment: I don't think you can. Why don't you just merge them locally and push the result afterwards.

Comment: because client and server are not related .. the only connection between them is that they belong to the same project

Comment: I know they are not related.. Add 2 modules.. one 'server' and one 'client' and push them to some new repository for example. I never heard about merging option on Github.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that we follow these steps:

- Create a new empty repository `App` or whatever
- Make an initial commit because we need one before we do a merge.
- Add a remote to old repository OldA.
- Merge OldA/master to New/master.
- Make a subdirectory OldA
- Move all files into subdirectory OldA.
- Commit all of the file moves.
- Repeat 3-6 for OldB.

Comment: how do I Merge OldA/master to New/master?

Comment: @MD10 Inside of New/master do .. 'git merge OldA'

Comment: I created the new folder and added the server origin- then did  git merge server/master but it says merge: server/master - not something we can merge